# Linux various partition type codes usage

Tags: partition

I was reading "Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019" - [Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019).

I noticed that the partition type codes used by the author are uncommon:

```
sgdisk --typecode=1:8301 --typecode=2:ef02 --typecode=3:ef00 --typecode=5:8301 $DEV
```

In a standard linux installation, I can see these two type codes: `8300` and `8200`.

These are the names per partition type code:

```
$ sgdisk -L
0700 Microsoft basic data  0c01 Microsoft reserved    2700 Windows RE          
3000 ONIE boot             3001 ONIE config           3900 Plan 9              
4100 PowerPC PReP boot     4200 Windows LDM data      4201 Windows LDM metadata
4202 Windows Storage Spac  7501 IBM GPFS              7f00 ChromeOS kernel     
7f01 ChromeOS root         7f02 ChromeOS reserved     8200 Linux swap          
8300 Linux filesystem      8301 Linux reserved        8302 Linux /home         
8303 Linux x86 root (/)    8304 Linux x86-64 root (/  8305 Linux ARM64 root (/)
8306 Linux /srv            8307 Linux ARM32 root (/)  8400 Intel Rapid Start   
8e00 Linux LVM             a000 Android bootloader    a001 Android bootloader 2
a002 Android boot          a003 Android recovery      a004 Android misc        
a005 Android metadata      a006 Android system        a007 Android cache       
a008 Android data          a009 Android persistent    a00a Android factory     
a00b Android fastboot/ter  a00c Android OEM           a500 FreeBSD disklabel   
a501 FreeBSD boot          a502 FreeBSD swap          a503 FreeBSD UFS         
a504 FreeBSD ZFS           a505 FreeBSD Vinum/RAID    a580 Midnight BSD data   
a581 Midnight BSD boot     a582 Midnight BSD swap     a583 Midnight BSD UFS    
a584 Midnight BSD ZFS      a585 Midnight BSD Vinum    a600 OpenBSD disklabel   
a800 Apple UFS             a901 NetBSD swap           a902 NetBSD FFS          
a903 NetBSD LFS            a904 NetBSD concatenated   a905 NetBSD encrypted    
a906 NetBSD RAID           ab00 Recovery HD           af00 Apple HFS/HFS+      
af01 Apple RAID            af02 Apple RAID offline    af03 Apple label         
af04 AppleTV recovery      af05 Apple Core Storage    af06 Apple SoftRAID Statu
af07 Apple SoftRAID Scrat  af08 Apple SoftRAID Volum  af09 Apple SoftRAID Cache
b300 QNX6 Power-Safe       bc00 Acronis Secure Zone   be00 Solaris boot        
bf00 Solaris root          bf01 Solaris /usr & Mac Z  bf02 Solaris swap        
bf03 Solaris backup        bf04 Solaris /var          bf05 Solaris /home       
bf06 Solaris alternate se  bf07 Solaris Reserved 1    bf08 Solaris Reserved 2  
bf09 Solaris Reserved 3    bf0a Solaris Reserved 4    bf0b Solaris Reserved 5  
c001 HP-UX data            c002 HP-UX service         e100 ONIE boot           
e101 ONIE config           ea00 Freedesktop $BOOT     eb00 Haiku BFS           
ed00 Sony system partitio  ed01 Lenovo system partit  ef00 EFI System          
ef01 MBR partition scheme  ef02 BIOS boot partition   f800 Ceph OSD            
f801 Ceph dm-crypt OSD     f802 Ceph journal          f803 Ceph dm-crypt journa
f804 Ceph disk in creatio  f805 Ceph dm-crypt disk i  fb00 VMWare VMFS         
fb01 VMWare reserved       fc00 VMWare kcore crash p  fd00 Linux RAID
```

Thus we can easily interpret the type codes that the author has used:

- `8301` is "Linux reserved".
- `ef02` is "BIOS boot partition".
- `ef00` is "EFI System".

I don't understand as follows:

1. What is the usage of a partition type `8301`?
2. Why should someone use partition type `8301` instead of `8300` (i.e. "Linux filesystem") ?
3. When do we use the other specific Linux-partition ? For example, when do we use `8302` over the standard `8300` ?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1572410/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-linux-home-partition-code-8302 over on Super User for a nice explanation.